# "docker-compose up" fails with error

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to work on a project, but I need to use docker for running the app, but the `docker-compose up` command fails with this error:

```
System error: exec: "./wait_to_start": stat ./wait_to_start:
no such file or directory
```

The wait_to_start command is an executable python script in the subfolder backend/.

I need to determine why it cannot be executed. Either it's been searched in the wrong path, or there are access right problems, or maybe the wrong python version is used.

Can I debug it with details, or login with SSH and check the files on the virtual machine? I'm too unexperienced with Docker...

Comment: Docker is not a virtual machine (Docker Machine notwithstanding).  You can't SSH into a container unless it explicitly supports SSH *and* the container is still running (which yours likely isn't).

Answer (score 1):

You can either set the "workdir" metadata to make sure you are in the right place when you start a container or simply call `/backend/wait_to_start` instead of `./wait_to_start` so you remove the need to be in the proper directory.

Answer (score 1):

Do debug with `docker-compose` I would do this:

```
docker-compose run --entrypoint bash <servicename>
```

That should give you a prompt and let you inspect the file and working directory, so see what's wrong.